# Looking for a good workflow for re-texturing and re-creating UV

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm not familiar with Blender or 3D in general. So, I'll explain what I want to do with pictures. So, I have this model below:

[image: Frost jacket]

It comes with a color texture and UV map:

[image]

So, that looks bad. I want to fix it. Make it look something like this:

[image]

So, I get that far. But I can't make the texture to follow the new UV map.  I'm guessing I skipped several steps in my workflow. Any tips on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Research "baking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remap an image texture you can bake it using 2 different UV maps.

[image: baking with 2 UV maps]

**(1)** In the *UV Maps* list, make sure the source UV map ("UVMap") has the "camera" icon activated. This one is used for rendering. The other one ("New UVMap") is selected. It's the *active UV map* and is used for baking.

**(2)** In the *Shader Editor*, connect the *Image Texture* node to an *Emission* node and this one to the *Material Output* node. (You can omit the *Emission* node, then Blender will use one internally.).

**(3)** Add a new *Image Texture* node, and create an image for it with the little button in it. Make sure the *Image Texture* node is selected (white border) to tell Blender that this is the bake target.

**(4)** In the *Render Properties* tab switch the render engine to *Cycles*. Adjust the number of max samples and check the *Denoise* option if you like. (Since version 3.0, Blender can now denoise baked images). Select the *Emit* bake type. Hit the *Bake* button and check the result in the *Image Editor*.

**(5)** **Important**: Don't forget to save the image if you're happy with the result. There is a hint in the status bar. Images must be saved individually because they won't get saved if you save the blend file, close Blender, or when Blender crashes. Possible data loss!

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this before and kept getting a black image, tried multiple solutions offered by googling and went nowhere. But at least, it gave me some hints and figured out how to do it with Eevee.

Comment: You're welcome. I wonder how you did that with Eevee, because you can only bake textures with Cycles. If the result is black, this could be due to a value greater than 0 for the *Metallic* or *Subsurface Scattering* settings of the *Principled BSDF* node.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Maybe it's not really Eevee. It's some youtube instruction about PBR texture. I just remember that Eevee render engine was selected, not Cycles.