# Convert udims to single uv map

Tags: modeling, texturing

How to convert udims to a single uv map. I'm suffering through an issue. I have a car model that has Udims i want to convert the textures to a single uv map. My gpu cpu memory goes higher when enable texture mode or when i render the scene or car model and another problem is Sketchfab does not support Udims, I want to upload on sketchfab. And my texture size is 4k of udims.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to manually move the UVs to tile 1, save it and then, manually adjust each texture on every UV island

Comment: once you have created a new non-UDIM UV map, just bake the image textures using the new and the original UDIM UV map. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/293836/107598

Comment: Thank you it helped me.